# Using sudo command from Node NW app

Tags: node.js, sudo, node-webkit

I have a node nw app I'm building that runs several shell commands.  One of the commands needs sudo privileges to run.  What is the best and most secure way to request the user's password and execute this command?

Answer (score 1):

If you're aiming at OSX, there's a Node.js package called [sudo-prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo-prompt) that allows you to prompt the user for their password and execute shell commands with sudo. You can mix this with `sudo -K` to kill the sudo session and force the prompt each time you need the user's permission.

Comment: You can also use `sudo-prompt` on Linux.